# Jetpack compose how to align surface over coil image in card to the bottom of the card?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I can't come up with a solution how to move the *Surface* object to the bottom of the card (image), and maybe add some padding from the bottom.

This is what it should look like:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
Card(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(8.dp),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
                elevation = 4.dp,
                border = BorderStroke(2.dp, AppColors.mMain)) {

                AsyncImage(model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                    .data(it.background_image)
                    .crossfade(true)
                    .build(),
                    contentDescription = "Game Image")

                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(50.dp)
                    .padding(start = 35.dp, end = 35.dp),
                color = AppColors.mMain,
                    border = BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Black),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp)) {

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The modified code is as follows**:

```
Card(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(8.dp),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
                    elevation = 4.dp,
                    border = BorderStroke(2.dp, AppColors.mMain)
                ) {
                    Box {
                        AsyncImage(model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                            .data(it.background_image)
                            .crossfade(true)
                            .build(),
                            contentDescription = "Game Image")
                        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(50.dp)
                            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                            .padding(start = 35.dp, end = 35.dp, bottom = 15.dp),
                            color = AppColors.mMain,
                            border = BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Black),
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp)) {

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Box inside your card, put Image and Surface inside it and add .align(Alignment.BottomCenter) to your Surface's modifier.